# 'gcc' could not be spawned. Is it installed and on your path?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc, atom-editor

> `'gcc'` could not be spawned. Is it installed and on your path? If so please open an issue on the package spawning the process.

Facing this error in Atom editor while compiling C++ program with `gpp` extension. And I am using Ubuntu, and this error comes every time I compile C, C++, C#, Ruby, etc.

I have tried to change directory, and path too. But nothing happens. I tried different extension to compile but this same issue I am facing again and again.

I just installed Atom and performed 'Hello World' program of C, just to check that this is working or not but it's not.

I just except to get perfect output of program, well it's just Hello World. But one thing I wanted to say that this same problem i faced recently in Windows. But in Windows I changed `'PATH'` then is got solved but I don't know anything about Ubuntu so I don't know what to do.

Comment: And what is your answer to the question posed by Atom.  When you run `g++` from the command line, do you get anything useful?  On Unix (including Linux, including Ubuntu), you set PATH to include the directory where `gcc` and `g++` are installed.

Comment: Maybe you want: https://askubuntu.com/a/348657/479851

Answer (score 0):

This means you haven't GCC installed in your distro.
Install GCC from here https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC